# HTML, jquery adjust image size when displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to apply some CSS to a web page background but am a little unsure how to do so. I have a script that when someone clicks a button, it changes the background image. However, the images are not to scale and are not sized right. I want to add some style to the image but dont know where to do so. I am trying to add :

```
background:url(Pic/jungle.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
```

Into each image. So when someone does click a button, its a single image thats fits the screen nicely. Does anyone have any sugguestions about where I might go about adding these styles to the background image? Thank you for your time and help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <style>
      body 
      {
      background-image:url(Pic/jungle.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <button class="color" style="background-image: url('Pic/changebackground.png'); width:60px; height: 50px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-color: transparent;border:none;"></button>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
              var rotate = 0;
              var colors = ["url('Pic/hi.jpg')", "url('Pic/jungle.jpg')"];
              $('body').on("click", function () {

                  $(this).css({
                      'background-image': colors[rotate]
                  });
                  rotate++;
                  if (rotate >= 2) {
                      rotate = 0;
                  }     

              });   
          });

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course you have to apply those style to the element your background-image is displayed on, that’s `body` in your case. And after doing that, only change the `background-image` property, otherwise with `background` all other properties will be reset to their defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the background-property completely by using $(this).css('background'). Try using background-image instead.